# If $f(x)>g(x)$ after intersection it remains that way until next intersection.

Tags: calculus, functions, proof-writing

I want to know how to prove that if you have 2 functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. And if $f(x) > g (x)$ after an intersection then it remains that way until the next intersection.

Note: $f$ and $g$ are continuous functions.

Comment: Look up “intermediate value theorem”

Comment: I don't understand how Intermediate value theorem is used here but I do feel it's relevant to the proof.

Comment: Can you please post explanation as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If two continuous real-valued functions $f$ and $g$ do not intersect on the interval $(a, b)$ then the difference $f-g$ has the same sign on the interval.

That is an immediate consequence of the “intermediate value theorem”: If $f(x_1) - g(x_1) > 0$ and $f(x_2) - g(x_2) < 0$ then $f(x) -g(x) = 0$ for some $x$ between $x_1$ and $x_2$, contrary to the assumption.

Comment: Wait. I'm still confused at the point where you say: it is an immediate consequence of Intermediate value theorem.

Comment: I read the intermediate value theorem. It is only dealing with one function at a time.

Comment: @rert588: You apply the IVT to the function $h = f-g$

Comment: So, I'm just thinking that (f-g)(a) is positive and (f-g)(b) is negative. Then f-g does not have the same sign on the interval.

Comment: I managed to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$$

Note that $h(x) $ is continuous

The intermediate theorem state that if there is a change in sign of a continuous function $h(x)$ there must be at least one $c$ such that $h(c) =0$

That provides a point of intersection for $f$ and $g$